# Postgres JSONB column containing multiple JSON arrays, needing to update one array's element's attribute with another array's element's attribute

Tags: psql, postgresql-9.5

I have a Postgres 9.5 "registry" table with a column called "attributes", amongst the others, which is a jsonb. This jsonb contains several attributes, a few of which are in turn json arrays of complex elements.
One of such json arrays is named "locations", and is a typical registry of locations:

```
"locations" : [
    {
      "fax" : "",
      "email" : "a@b.com",
      "address" : "50 RockAndRoll Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11249, United States",
      "isHeadquarter" : false,
    },
    {
      "fax" : "1234567890",
      "email" : "",
      "address" : "50 TwistAndShout Drive, Brooklyn, NY 11249, United States",
      "isHeadquarter" : true,
  ],
```

Another such array is named "referencePeople", typically:

```
"referencePeople" : [
    {
      "mobile" : "+1234567890",
      "email" : "c@d.com",
      "name" : "Todd Dancer",
      "mainContact" : true,
    },
    {
      "mobile" : "+1234567890",
      "email" : "e@f.com",
      "name" : "Johnny Swing",
      "mainContact" : false,
  ],
```

(Please don't ask how I do I find myself facing such a situation ...).

Now, what I'm asked to do is, for each record of the registry table, I have to check whether:

```
attributes.locations[#].email is NULL AND attributes.locations[#].isHeadquarter = 'true'
```

if so fill it with:

```
attributes.locations[#].email = attributes.referencePeople[#].email
```

but only when:

```
attributes.referencePeople[#].email IS NOT NULL AND attributes.referencePeople[#].mainContact = 'true'
```

So, in the above example, I should do:

```
attributes.locations[1].email = attributes.referencePeople[0].email
```

I have tried several approaches using examples from other answers, but all of the ones I've found usually work directly on the whole jsonb column which is an array itself, not like in my case where I have a complex jsonb column containing multiple attributes, including some arrays.

Any idea on how could this be possibly done in PSQL? (and possibly avoiding procedures if e.g. a single WITH/UPDATE statement is possible)

Thanks in advance